# Enabling/disabling cursor in menu view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to bring up a menu where I can use a mouse to select buttons and the rest of the game is inactive. The mouse doesn't show up when it should. Any suggestions?

```
            using System.Collections;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using UnityEngine;
            using UnityEngine.UI;
            using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

            public class Puzzle1 : MonoBehaviour {
                public GameObject Mika;
                public GameObject ExploringUI;
                public GameObject InspectingUI;
                private bool menuOpen = false;

                void Update () {
                    RaycastHit hit;
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.J) && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 8f, 1<<8 | 1<<9)) {
                        if (menuOpen) {
                            Cursor.visible = (false);
                            menuOpen = false;
                            Mika.GetComponent<FirstPersonController> ().enabled = true;
                            ExploringUI.SetActive (true);
                            InspectingUI.SetActive (false);
                        } else {
                            Cursor.visible = (true);
                            menuOpen = true;
                            Mika.GetComponent<FirstPersonController> ().enabled = false;
                            ExploringUI.SetActive (false);
                            InspectingUI.SetActive (true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't editted the FPS controller.

> Unity's standard first person controller locks and hides the Cursor.

You can simply edit the script controlling this, but I can't specifically tell you where it is. The source may have changed and may be different between us.

Remove the FPS controller stuff from your script to test if that's the issue, the issue could also be in your other UI objects, but you haven't provided the source for them, so idk.

Comment: Cool, thank you! I was hoping that disabling the script would let me do what I want with the cursor again, but guess I'll have to play around with it to understand better.

Comment: Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;